# Same rows from one range copied when copying rows from another range

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copypaste a row with formula errors to another sheet.

The problem is in copying rows for:
"Run Formulas for MF, copy/paste to MF output sheet" (Second half).

It appears to copy the same rows that were in error for the "Run Formulas for Lago, copy/Paste to Lago Output Sheet" even though those cells were cleared of contents. I searched for any errors in those rows and there were none.

The same code works as intended on other spreadsheets.

My theory is that it is remembering the error rows and recopying them but it should reset when running the second time through.

```
'Run Formulas for Lago, copy/Paste to Lago Output Sheet
With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AT2:BC" & lrow).Formula = .Range("AT2:BC2").Formula
End With

With Worksheets("Fall").Range("A3:CU" & lrow)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set eRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not eRng Is Nothing Then
        Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), eRng.EntireRow).Copy
        Worksheets("Lago").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    End With
Range("AT3:BC" & lrow).ClearContents

'Run Formulas for MF, copy/paste to MF output sheet
With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BE2:BN" & lrow).Formula = .Range("BE2:BN2").Formula
End With

With Worksheets("Fall").Range("A3:CU" & lrow)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set eRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not eRng Is Nothing Then
        Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), eRng.EntireRow).Copy
        Worksheets("MF").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    End With
Range("BE3:BN" & lrow).ClearContents
```

Comment: Watch out for those `ActiveSheet` references - they might be screwing things up.

Comment: Why are you using `With Worksheets("Fall")` and then  `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`? also, you miss some dots to reference your with on the same line, `Rows.Count, 1` should be `.Rows.Count, 1` if it's referencing the worksheet Fall. Looks like you know how to qualify and reference worksheets, I'd recommend get rid of all the `ActiveSheet` and fully qualify your ranges.

Comment: @SJR thanks for the tip I'll play around and see if that's the problem.

Comment: @Damian The `With Worksheets("Fall")` is there because I get a compile reference error without it. I also want to make sure it's referencing the right sheet in the workbook. The `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is to make sure it's using last row on the active sheet.

Comment: @Deke like SJR said, don't ever use the `ActiveSheet`reference all the sheets you are working with and then use the references. Update your code after that and if you still have problems tell us exactly where and will be able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure it's the right sheet because until near the end the active sheet doesn't change. Anyway remove all doubt and follow Damian's advice.

Comment: Okay I've removed all activesheet references. Still getting the issue. I'm pretty sure what it's doing is remembering the last row that was an error and copying it. The issue seems to be with `If Not eRng Is Nothing Then` statement. It's not registering there is no error. It's just going to whatever was last copied when there is no error. IF there is an error it works correctly and will copy only that error row.

Comment: Are you saying `eRng` is nothing but the code continues anyway? That doesn't seem possible. Have you stepped through your code using F8?

Comment: Yes and yes.... That's why i'm totally stumped. This works perfectly on every other spreadsheet that has this code but this one seems to ignore it's own logic. lol I've been banging my head on this issue for two days.

Comment: Does it fail on the first block or the second? Have you put dots everywhere you were lacking them (or a sheet reference)? Your second block is missing `on error goto 0`.

Comment: first block runs fine, Second block is where it fails. `on error goto 0` is back in place. I had removed it and the other on error to see if it was coming up with unexpected errors or not. Still fails on second block though.

Comment: The OEG0 line needs to be before the If.

Comment: Sorry fixed that... but still has the issue.

Comment: Must be something in the code you haven't posted. Is `erng` declared as a Range?

Comment: I do have it declared. but found the answer. Set below.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Run Formulas for Lago, copy/Paste to Lago Output Sheet
With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AT2:BC" & lrow).Formula = .Range("AT2:BC2").Formula
End With

With Worksheets("Fall").Range("A3:CU" & lrow)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set eRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not eRng Is Nothing Then
        Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), eRng.EntireRow).Copy
        Worksheets("Lago").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    End With
Range("AT3:BC" & lrow).ClearContents

'Run Formulas for MF, copy/paste to MF output sheet
With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BE2:BN" & lrow).Formula = .Range("BE2:BN2").Formula
End With

With Worksheets("Fall").Range("A3:CU" & lrow)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set eRg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) '<---- Changed to eRg from eRng
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not eRg Is Nothing Then '<---- Changed to eRg from eRng
        Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:CU"), eRng.EntireRow).Copy
        Worksheets("MF").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    End With
  Range("BE3:BN" & lrow).ClearContents
```

Comment: I had to create a new reference for the range. So I changed eRng to eRg in the second block and added a second Dim eRg as Range.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that, though could argue it's good practice.

Comment: Totally agree. It should just reset in the second block. Still open to idea's and solutions though. It's just this is something that works.